# Find real numbers that makes two different equations the same curve

Tags: calculus

[image]

I'm taking a vector calculus course, and I'm having trouble with this question. I know that I can make $B$ into $A$ (for the $x$ component) by multiplying $X$ by $t^3$ , which will be $t + t^3$, but I'm not sure how to find the bounds from this alone. I can also make them into vectors, but I'm just not sure how to go about finding the values for $a$ and $b$. A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that $t$ in the equations for $A$ is replaced with $t^{1/3}$ in the equations for $B$. (Note this is substituting, not multiplying as you wrote.) To compensate for that, replace the limits in $A$ with their cubes in the limits for $B$. Therefore, set

$$a=-8,\quad b=8$$

You can check this by calculating the starting and ending points of both curves. In the first, the starting point is $x=(-2)+(-2)^3=-10$ and $y=3+(-2)^2=7$. In the second, the starting point is $x=(-8)^{1/3}+(-8)=-10$ and $y=3+(-8)^{2/3}=7$, so these agree. Do the same for the ending points and you are done.